# Add and update new elements to an arraylist

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jakarta-ee, enterprise

I'm attempting to check an arraylist containing an element(celebrity) for an email address inputted by the user then if it's in the list it'd be updated but if not a new instance would be created. The issue I'm having is: when I input a new celebrity it'll display duplicate entries of it.

Output:

```
[
    Celebrity [firstName=Frank, lastName=Sinatra, netWorth=1000000.0, email=frank.sinatra@smoothjazz.com], 
    Celebrity [firstName=Michael, lastName=Jackson, netWorth=1.0E9, email=king_of_pop@mtv.com], 
    Celebrity [firstName=Aaron, lastName=Hoffman, netWorth=10000.0, email=iamsonreal@iamsonreal.com], 
    Celebrity [firstName=new, lastName=new, netWorth=900.0, email=new@y.com], 
    Celebrity [firstName=new, lastName=new, netWorth=900.0, email=new@y.com], 
    Celebrity [firstName=new, lastName=new, netWorth=900.0, email=new@y.com]
]
```

```
if (celeb.getEmail().contains(request.getParameter("email"))) { 
    celeb.setNetWorth(Double.parseDouble((request.getParameter("netWorth"))));  
} else {
    Celebrity cel = new Celebrity(request.getParameter("firstName"),
            request.getParameter("lastName"), request.getParameter("email"),
            Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("netWorth")));
    celebrityList.add(cel);
}
```

https://repl.it/repls/FumblingOrderlyEllipses (Full code)

Comment: and, what seems to be the trouble young Jamy?

Comment: Please add context to your question to make it easy to understand. Also a decent [mcve] code post would be worth much here.

Comment: I would guess that some or all of your fields are static?

Comment: You're doing this `if` statement inside a loop such as `for(Celebrity celeb : celebrityList)`, yes?

Comment: The issue is it's storing the new celebrity more than once. The if statements are inside a loop

Comment: @Jamy So don't put them in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding a new Celebrity to your list for every iteration of your check.

Always write code the way you would explain it to someone else.  So the correct (pseudo) code becomes:

```
if (emailExistsInList(data.email))
  updateExistingCeleb(data);
else
  addNewCeleb(data);

...

boolean emailExistsInList(String email){
  for (Celebrity celeb: celebs)
    if (celeb.email.equals(email)) return true;
  }
}

void updateExistingCeleb(String email, CelebData data){
  // your search and update code here 
}

void addNewCeleb(CelebData data){
  Celeb newCeleb = // your instantiation logic here
  celebs.add(newCeleb);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. @Joeri Hendrickx